# How do I use multiple variables in an MySQL query in node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, server-side

I am trying to insert student data into a table with the parent key as a foreign key. The parent data is sent in the same JSON object, with a student array inside of it. I want to select the parent Id of the same object sent by writing the parent data to the database, then select the Id where the address and firstname is the same as the one sent. Also if you think I should do it a more effecient way, its welcome. Also I am fairly new to node and how http servers work.
Code for getting the JSON Object

```
router.post('/scholarship', function(req, res) {            //post request to /members... use as model for /application, etc
console.log('post to api/scholarship');
console.log(req);          //req.body is the data you handle (save to mysql database)
res.send(req.body);
scholarReq = (req.body);});
```

Code for writing to the Database

```
function insertIntoStudent(jsonpack){
var parentId;
parentId = connectToDatabase.query("SELECT memberId FROM Members WHERE address = ? AND firstName = ?", [jsonpack.user.address , jsonpack.user.firstName]);
for (var i = 0; i > jsonpack.user.students.length; i++){
    if (jsonpack.user.student[i].first != ""){
        connectToDatabase.query("INSERT INTO Students(firstName) VALUES (?)",[jsonpack.user.student[i].first]);
    }
    if (jsonpack.user.student[i].last != ""){
        connectToDatabase.query("INSERT INTO Students(lastName) VALUES (?)",[jsonpack.user.student[i].last]);
    }
    if (jsonpack.user.student[i].grade != ""){
        connectToDatabase.query("INSERT INTO Students(grade) VALUES (?)",[jsonpack.user.student[i].grade]);
    }
    if (jsonpack.user.student[i].unit != ""){
        connectToDatabase.query("INSERT INTO Students(unit) VALUES (?)",[jsonpack.user.student[i].unit]);
    }
}
```

Any help is great. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I mean, if the parameterized option isn't working, you could always fall back to connection.escape(...)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly you mean something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i > jsonpack.user.students.length; i++){
    var user = jsonpack.user.student[i];
    connectToDatabase.query("INSERT INTO Students(firstName,lastname,grade,unit) VALUES (?,?,?,?),[user.first,user.last,user.grade,user.unit])
}
```